# Wordpress pagination on static front page always shows same posts

Tags: wordpress, pagination, posts

I have a problem with pagination on my front page. I want to show all posts from a specific category and paginate them. Here is the code:

```
if ( is_front_page() ) {     
$paged = get_query_var( 'page' ) ? get_query_var( 'page' ) : 1;
$args = array(
    'post_type'      => 'post',
    'orderby'        => 'date',
    'order'          => 'DESC',
    'posts_per_page' => 1,
    'cat'            => '4',
    'page'           => $paged,
); 
$q = new WP_Query( $args );
if ( $q->have_posts() ) { 
    while ( $q->have_posts() ) {
        $q->the_post();
        ?>
        <div> .... </div>
        <?php
    }
    //pagination links
    wp_reset_query();
}
```

}

But all the time I have the same posts on different pages: domain.com/page/2/ etc. What I'm doing wrong? How to fix it?

Thank you for any help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using `wp_reset_postdata()` instead of `wp_reset_query()`.